# How to add list items to recyclerView dynamically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I fetch data with Retrofit using. I have 10 results per page. When I scroll to the last result, there is no further possibility to view the туче results. So, I need to update the adapter. but nothing comes of it. Here is part of my code:
retrofit:

```
    private final RestClient restClient;
    private List<Data> newData;
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter;

public void fetchData() {
    Call<Data> callItems = restClient.searchData();
    callItems.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Data> call, @NonNull Response<Data> response) {
        newData = response.body().getPersons();
        personAdapter.addPersons(newData );
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Data> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

here is my method from adpter class where I add new items:

```
 private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
..................

    public void addIPersons(List<Person> newPerson) {
        this.iersons= newIPeroon
        persons.addAll(newIPerson;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: The question is not that clear.. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You should use mutable list and should not overwrite it.
But the better way is to use listadapter

Answer (score 0):

Just update your data source and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

After adding to your list like this:

```
persons.add(newIPerson);
```

call:

```
dataAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```